# Why does TortoisePlink.exe show "No supported authentication methods available" where plink.exe works fine?

Tags: windows-vista, ssh, putty, tortoise-hg, tortoise-git

I have both [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) 2.3 64 bit and [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) 1.7.7 64 bit installed on Vista 64 bit.

Both TortoiseHg (`ssh = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -C -batch` entry in `mercurial.ini`) and TortoiseGit (`GIT_SSH` environment variable set to `C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoisePlink.exe`) are configured to use PuTTy's [plink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY#Applications) (command-line interface to the PuTTY back ends) versions distributed with them.

I have [Pageant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY#Applications) (PuTTy authentification client) running and proper ssh key loaded. However any `hg` or `git` command results in error dialog titled **PuTTY Fatal Error** being displayed with the message:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available. (server sent:publickey)

At the same time using *original* plink.exe provided with PuTTy works.

Why doesn't TortoisePlink work?

Comment: It seems the authors of Tortoise* used a modified plink to show you a password prompt and in the process may have made it incompatible with other methods of authentication. Could you point the configuration files to the original plink and see what happens?

Comment: Setting the original plink in configuration files solves the problem but I'm curious why branded versions do not work. Especially since I remember that the one from hg used to work in the past.

Comment: @billc.cn - TortoisePlink have **only** modal windows on disconnect removed

Comment: Have you tried to remove all and any command-line parameters for Mercurial (maybe only adding -v is good idea)

Comment: @LazyBadger What parameters do You have in mind?

Comment: With `ssh = "c:\Program Files\_Tools\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe"` only I work with my Pageant (x32, if it matter)

Comment: Are you sure that you added your private key to Pageant?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with 64-bit TortoiseSVN working with 32-bit pageant. Either use 32-bit TortoiseSVN (IMO there is no real need for it to be 64-bit). Unofficially, the devs only supply 32-bit binaries. A 64-bit build of PuTTY is available [here](https://blog.splunk.net/wp/64bit-putty/).

[It seems that the TortoiseSVN devs put the blame on PuTTY...](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=2891652)

Answer (score 0):

You can get such cryptic error message for many reasons. If it works with original plink though, chances are that there is something wrong with TortoisePLink and Sam's answer might help.

Nevertheless, it's not (entirely) true that you need 64-bit putty with 64-bit TortoisePLink. I am happily committing over 64-bit TortoisePLink taking keys from 32-bit pageant.

You aren't listing full URL of the repository and the connection info used with putty. Perhaps there is a subtle difference that's causing one to break while the other works.

Generally, the error message is telling you that there's no match between server keys and client keys. One instance where this is likely to happen is when you use incorrect username (e.g. yourusername@bitbucket.org instead of hg@bitbucket.org).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with TortoiseSVN, Windows 7 64 bit. Just getting the 64 bit version of Putty/Pageant did not do the trick, I continued to get the same errors. What did work for me was what is an alternative checkout URL format listed under the "Configuration Variants (pageant)" section of [this page](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto_logemann.html), which essentially says that instead of putting the FQDN of your server, you can just put your PuTTY session name in the checkout URL:

```
svn+ssh://[remote-username]@[putty-session-name]/usr/local/svn/repos/myrepo
```